# Manipulating elements in a dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to iterate through a dictionary of dataframes. For each df in the dictionary I am attempting to append two columns to a list, perform a few operations, and then append this list to a separate master dataframe.

How I am trying to access each element of the dictionary:

```
for k in range(len(dict_of_df)):
    l = dict_of_df[['Name1', 'Name2']][k].to_list()
```

I am then trying to drop any duplicates form this list, and append a combination of the remaining items into two separate columns of a master df.

For instance, given the following dataframe from the start:

```
Name1    Name2    Color    Size
 Jim      Bob      R         L
 Sam      Jim      G         S
```

The column `Name1 & Name2` would be sent to a list like so:

```
 l
Jim
Bob
Sam
Jim
```

Dropping the duplicates would leave:

```
 l
Jim
Bob
Sam
```

And inserting a combination of these items into the master df would yield:

```
 Name1   Name2
  Jim     Bob
  Jim     Sam
  Sam     Bob
```

Comment: check with combination itertools

Comment: Does the ordering of pairs in each row matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations`, taking two at a time. Flatten your name columns, then drop duplicates before taking combinations.

```
# pandas >= 0.24
from itertools import combinations

names = pd.Series(
    df[['Name1', 'Name2']].to_numpy().ravel()).drop_duplicates()
pd.DataFrame(combinations(names, 2), columns=['name1', 'name2'])

  name1 name2
0   Jim   Bob
1   Jim   Sam
2   Bob   Sam
```

---

```
# pandas < 0.24
# .to_numpy() -> .values
# combinations(...) -> list(combinations(...)) # iterators not supported
names = pd.Series(df[['Name1', 'Name2']].values.ravel()).drop_duplicates()
pd.DataFrame([*combinations(names, 2)], columns=['name1', 'name2'])

  name1 name2
0   Jim   Bob
1   Jim   Sam
2   Bob   Sam
```

Comment: Does `like='Name'` Just get all columns containing 'Name'? I guess I am trying to avoid that because the real case the columns are named completely differently.

Comment: @MaxB Yes, for brevity sake. You can use `df[['Name1', 'Name2']]` if that works better.